# Can two or more conditional statements placed inside a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation, if-statement

I am newbie in JavaScript. Can't find answer for this. I am not sure whether it is relevant.
I have a registration form with 2 fields.On submit, it should be validated. Here in my code, first written if condition only works. If the first if statement is commented, second if condition works.

HTML CODE :

```
<body>
        <div align="center">
            <h1>REGISTRATION</h1>

            <form action="" method="post" name="reg">
                    <table>         
                        <tr>
                            <td><label> Enter Full Name : </label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="id1" name="username" placeholder="minimum 6 charactors"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><td></td><td><label style="color:red;" id="label1"></label></td></tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td><label> Gender : </label></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"><label> Female </label>
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"><label> Male </label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><td></td><td><label style="color:red;" id="label2"></label></td></tr>


                    </table>
                    <br/><button name="submit" value="submit" onclick="return validate_form()">Submit</button>  
            </form>

        </div>

    </body>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            function validate_form () 
            {
                var name=document.getElementById("id1").value;
                var gender=document.getElementsByName("gender");

                if(name=="")
                {
                    document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML="Enter Name";
                    return false;
                }
                else if(name.length<6)
                {
                    document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML="Minimum 6 charactors";
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
                if(gender.checked)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById("label2").innerHTML="Check gender";
                    return false;
                }
            }

        </script>
```

In JSFiddle, it gives a error like

```
{"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x56ae150>, 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x56b3ed0>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_wrap', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x56ae150>, 'html_name': 'js_wrap', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_wrap', 'label': u'Js wrap', 'field': <django.forms.fields.TypedChoiceField object at 0x5c03510>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_wrap'}"}
```

I donno what this error means!

Comment: what you trying to say ? what output you expect ?

Comment: The first if block always returns, it never reaches the second

Comment: _return ends the current function and returns execution flow to the calling function_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to rewrite your validation code a bit.
Check demo - [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/51vzm4L4/):

Your problems:

1. function returns before `gender` is checked;
2. you cannot check multiple checkboxes this way: `if(gender.checked)`

Below is the working code

```
    function validate_form() {
        var name = document.getElementById("id1").value,
            gender = document.getElementsByName("gender"),
            result = true,
            genderPass = 0;

        if (name == "") {
            document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML = "Enter Name";
            result = false;
        } else if (name.length < 6) {
            document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML = "Minimum 6 charactors";
            result = false;
        } else {
          document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML = "";
      }

        Array.prototype.forEach.call(gender, function(item) {
            genderPass += item.checked ? 1 : 0
        });
        if (genderPass === 0) {
            document.getElementById("label2").innerHTML = "Check gender";
            result = false;
        } else {
          document.getElementById("label2").innerHTML = "";
      }


        return result;
    }
```

```js
    function validate_form() {
        var name = document.getElementById("id1").value,
            gender = document.getElementsByName("gender"),
            result = true,
            genderPass = 0;

        if (name == "") {
            document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML = "Enter Name";
            result = false;
        } else if (name.length < 6) {
            document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML = "Minimum 6 charactors";
            result = false;
        } else {
          document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML = "";
      }

        Array.prototype.forEach.call(gender, function(item) {
            genderPass += item.checked ? 1 : 0
        });
        if (genderPass === 0) {
            document.getElementById("label2").innerHTML = "Check gender";
            result = false;
        } else {
          document.getElementById("label2").innerHTML = "";
      }


        return result;
    }
```

```html
        <div align="center">
            <h1>REGISTRATION</h1>

            <form action="" method="post" name="reg">
                    <table>         
                        <tr>
                            <td><label> Enter Full Name : </label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="id1" name="username" placeholder="minimum 6 charactors"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><td></td><td><label style="color:red;" id="label1"></label></td></tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td><label> Gender : </label></td>
                                <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"><label> Female </label>
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"><label> Male </label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><td></td><td><label style="color:red;" id="label2"></label></td></tr>


                    </table>
                    <br/><button name="submit" value="submit" onclick="return validate_form();">Submit</button>  
            </form>

        </div>
```

Comment: _you cannot check checkboxes this way_ ? You can if the `gender` is an object not a nodelist and `gender` returns object which has property `checked`

Comment: There are two of them. But edited my answer, thanks!

Comment: the error message don't go even after it is rectified.

Answer (score 1):

When the function hits a `return` line, it leaves (ie returns from) the function and doesn't execute anything else in that function.

What people usually do is have a variable called `valid` or something similar that defaults to `true`. Then they have `if` statements that check only for things that would make the form invalid. If one of those `if` statements gets tripped, it handles the issue (eg telling the user that they need to fill in their gender) and sets `valid` to false. At the end, and only at the end, it returns `valid`. This way, if anything is making the form invalid, the function will return invalid, but nothing bad will happen if more than one `if` statement gets tripped because you can set `valid` to be `false` as many times as you want without causing any issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            function validate_form () 
            {
                var name=document.getElementById("id1").value;
                var gender=document.getElementsByName("gender");

                var boolValidateName = validateName(name);
                var boolValidateGnder = validateGnder(name);

                if(boolValidateName && boolValidateGnder){

                    //if both are validate
                }else{
                    //if either of or both not validate
                }


            }

            var validateName = function (name){

                if(name=="")
                {
                    document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML="Enter Name";
                    return false;
                }
                else if(name.length<6)
                {
                    document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML="Minimum 6 charactors";
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }

            }

            var validateGender = function(gender){

                if(gender.checked)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById("label2").innerHTML="Check gender";
                    return false;
                }

            }

        </script>
```

Your `return` statement is not placed very well.
You can break your business login into `function` and call it.So,every return statement get an equal chance to run.

Comment: we use 3 functions here na..??my question is can we check in just 1 function

Comment: Ofcourse.But what is matter is your code should clean.there should be less coupling.You can write whole things in one function.but its not readable for other developer even for you if go to work on the same code some day later.So I factored your function in different function.So later you can extends your condition without too much of adjustment

Answer (score 1):

> `getElementsByName` will return `nodelist`. You will have to iterate it to get the checked value.

Also note, *return ends the current function and returns execution flow to the calling function* hence any line of code after execution of `return` will not be executed.

Do not forget to empty(`''`) the error messages.

Try this:

```js
function validate_form() {
  var name = document.getElementById("id1").value;
  var gender = document.getElementsByName("gender");
  document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML = '';
  document.getElementById("label2").innerHTML = '';
  var genValue = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < gender.length; i++) {
    if (gender[i].checked) {
      genValue = gender[i].value;
    }
  }
  if (!name) {
    document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML = "Enter Name";
    return false;
  } else if (name.length < 6) {
    document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML = "Minimum 6 charactors";
    return false;
  } else if (!genValue) {
    document.getElementById("label2").innerHTML = "Check gender";
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<div align="center">
  <h1>REGISTRATION</h1>
  <form action="" method="post" name="reg">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Enter Full Name :</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="id1" name="username" placeholder="minimum 6 charactors">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <label style="color:red;" id="label1"></label>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Gender :</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
          <label>Female</label>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">
          <label>Male</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <label style="color:red;" id="label2"></label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <button name="submit" value="submit" onclick="return validate_form()">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/ey5pr4fy/)

Comment: thanx it worked..but the gender.checked worked when it was alone in the if condition.

Comment: What do you mean by alone? If you use getElementById then it will work on single element

Comment: In my code,if the first if condition of name is removed,the if condition for gender works fine without iteration for it. Sorry, I don't know much in javascript. may be that is the reason i have this dbt!

Comment: `gender.checked` will return 2 elements as there are 2 elements having name as `gender`. If you do not iterate and apply condition, it will look for a property `checked` of `NodeList` which does not exist. If you do not iterate and check, value of `gender.chekced` will be `undefined` which is _falsey_ value hence it will show the error of 'Check gender'. I hope this clears your doubt :)

Comment: tanx for clearing..but if we put both fields blank..only 1 field error comes at a time.

Answer (score 0):

When your first block of if..else statements returns, it returns for the whole function and the if for gender never even runs.  remove:

```
  else
  {
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: What to write instead of it?

Comment: Nothing.  Just remove it.  an if statement doesn't necessarily have to have an else.

Comment: However, this only directly answers the specific question that you asked.  As others here have pointed out, you'll need to change the way your validating gender as well.